# How do I compare two lists in Java and print the result based on each combination?

Tags: java

I want to compute ticket price between each stations based on the price matrix:

```
        a  b c 

  a     0  2 3
  b     4  0 1
  c     7  2 0
```

Example:  `from a to b` print `2` or `from c to a` print `7` based on values in the above price matrix.

Here it is, I want to print the railway ticket fare based on the two station lists: "from:" list and "to:" list. I want to print fare after comparing. There is a fixed fare for each combination. For example station a to station b, the fare is 10. For any one station to other station there is a fixed fare.

Comment: Can you clarify? Please give an extended example. so if you had 2 strings bca and acb, you would print "294"???

Comment: here it is i want to print the raileway ticket fare based on the two list of sations list one "from:", list two "to:" . i want to print fare after comparing. there is a fixed fare for each combination.
from station a to station b fare is 10.

Comment: from any one station to any other station there is a fixed fare and it could be any combination.

Comment: @kurt ortan, please edit to improve your question so others can answer  it.

Comment: I still don't quite understand what the input and output is supposed to be...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a class, which is responsible for storing the fares.

```
public class FareStorage {
    Map<TownCombination, Double> fares;

    //...

    public double getFare(String townA, String townB) {
        return fares.get(new TownCombination(townA, townB));
    }

    public void addFare(String townA, String townB, double fare) {
        fares.put(new TownCombination(townA, townB));
    }

    class TownCombination {
        String town1;
        String town2;

        //If a fare from A to B is equals the fare from B to A, 
        //then the A-B and the B-A combinations should be equal. 
        //Override hashCode and equals the way you want.  
    }
}
```

It is not complete, but I hope you get the idea. This is how you can use it:

```
        FareStorage storage = new FareStorage();
        storage.addFare("A", "B", 10.2);

        //....
        double fare = storage.get("A", "B");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [guava's](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) [Table](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Table.html).

**Exmaple:**

```
Table<Integer, String, String> table = HashBasedTable.create();
table.put(1, "a", "1a");
table.put(1, "b", "1b");
table.put(2, "a", "2a");
table.put(2, "b", "2b");
```